# Convert a scanned plot to a digital one

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing

Let's say that i have a scanned document and somehow i have managed to clear it from grid lines, extra character and the output is something like this.

[image]

I wanna convert it to digital format and plot it with `matplotlib` lets say.
How should i proceed on that? Any suggestions ?
I have tried to flatten the image and then plot it but the output was not even close.

Comment: Sample coordinates on the line, do a cubic spline interpolation.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Hello, thank you for the cubic spine idea. I am confused on how should i convert the image to an array though

Comment: Pixel coordinates. I'd recommend doing it by hand for something this small

Comment: @MadPhysicist the picture is just for example. It is quite big picture in reality.

Comment: Get each peak, inflection point, and a couple of points in between. There are plenty of softwares that will record click coordinates for you. You'll get a result much faster and more accurately than trying to concoct the right processing algorithm. Unless you want something already canned, which is off topic for SO. Your question, as it stands, is too broad by the way, but I'm making suggestions because the subject is interesting, regardless of whether it's on topic or not.